# Problems registering/loading a 64 bit .NET dll

Tags: com, 64-bit, activex

I have a VB client app that calls a VB in-process COM server `myprogressbar`.

(Yes, this is a perverse way for VB to call VB, but the client is a test harness - in production code the client is not VB and needs to use COM).

```
Dim progressbar As Object = CreateObject("myprogressbar.myprogressbar")
progressbar.showform()
```

This fails with the error

`System.Exception: cannot create ActiveX component`.

The x86 server is registered (successfully) with

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe x86\Release\myprogressbar.dll
```

And the x64 server is registered (successfully) with

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe x64\Release\myprogressbar.dll
```

**Update:** same thing happens with a single server compiled as `Any CPU`.  Any previous report of the x86 version working was only down to a previous install still being registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this.

The problem is that .NET assemblies, unless loaded into the GAC, need registering with the `/c` switch to `regasm` (which registers a full path to the codebase), so the executable can find them at runtime.  This is in contrast to `regsvr32` which has this sort of behaviour by default.